# Obtain PublicationPath from Deployer API

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, api

I'm trying to access the publication data (**PUBLICATION_PATH**) by its **publicationId** in a java class with the **deployer API,** but I'm not able to find any class or method to map the Publication object.

With odata seems too complicated to such a little need, and I'm not sure I can access de odata webservice.

" ... new Publication(pubId); " creates an empty publication.

Is there a way to access de persistence model of the database? My solution is in the following class/method:

```
JPAPublicationDAO.findById(int publicationId)
```

In the public API the only class of JPA is "JPAQueryDAO". So I don't know if it's possible to access JPAPublicationDAO.

Does anyone knows how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to get a publication already stored in the Broker storage is to use the `PublicationDAO`. Here is an example of how this could be done (for a publication if Id=3):

```
final int publicationId = 3;
final PublicationDAO publicationDAO = (PublicationDAO) StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(publicationId, StorageTypeMapping.PUBLICATION);
final Publication publication = publicationDAO.findById(publicationId);
if (publication != null) {
    System.out.println(publication.getPublicationPath());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! That was exactly what I was looking for! I think is a general way to access DAO objects.

Comment: Correct Raul. This is a generic mechanism to access the Broker storage. You can replace "publication" with the type you're interested and it will probably work. The DAO interfaces are defined in the "com.tridion.storage.dao" package.

Answer (score 2):

In a deployer extension you should probably use the `com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.Publication` class, but can't really find a good example right now.

It seems like you'd have to load this from the current ProcessingInstructions rather than trying to initialize a new one (as it could be the first time you're publishing something from a given publication and therefore the `Storage` layer wouldn't know about this publication yet).